# Looking for software to play back incoming network traffic

Tags: networking

I have the following situation:
Application A contacts an http server S, sending request(s and receiving answer(s).
I would like to capture exchanges between A and S, and then play back the answers without A really contacting S. For example, I intercept a request from A to S, and instead of forwarding it further to S I reply to A locally with a previously recorded S answer. So, A thinks it talks with S, while in real it talks with my interceptor.
Does such software exist (for Windows 7)? Thanks.

Comment: To the off-topic downvoter - this is very much *on-topic*. Replaying the traffic is essential part of testing/profiling/benchmarking the network-facing code.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "replay pcap dump" gave me [this link](http://xmodulo.com/how-to-capture-and-replay-network-traffic-on-linux.html) (`tcpdump`, `tcprewrite`, `tcpreplay`).

Adding "windows" to the search string gave me [this one](https://www.darknet.org.uk/2007/03/preplay-a-pcap-network-traffic-replay-tool-for-windows/) (`preplay`).

And finally, "tcpreplay windows" gave me [this](http://tcpreplay.synfin.net/wiki/manual), so aparently the trustworthy `tcpreplay` is cross platform enough for your purpose.

Works for you?

Comment: I was aware about the first one, but not of the second. Will have a look, thanks.